# Access same android calendar events on different devices

Tags: android, calendar

I am writing an app that creates, updates and deletes events in the android calendar (google calendar) using the Calendar Provider API. It should be possible to manipulate the events created by that app from different devices.

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html events are stored in a table (CalendarContract.Events) on the device and the EVENT_ID corresponds to the _ID field in the table. It *seems logical* that this EVENT_ID is device-specific.

Let us assume that my app creates an event "My Event" with ID 1 on "Device 1" in "My Shared Calendar". Given a second device that synchronizes with the shared calendar, the device specific EVENT_ID 1 from the first device is useless on the second device.

Now, my question is: How can I identify "My Event" on that second device?  Is this possible with the calendar provider API, or do I have to use the google calendar API?

Comment: Why do you need to know what the ID is of the event? The ID is just a local ID. What are you trying to do that you need to know what `My Event` is?

Comment: Because the app should be able to modify "My Event" on the second device, too. To be more precise: if two devices modify "My Event" then it has to be ensured that both are talking about the same event. In order to do so, I think it is necessary to correctly identify "My Event".